# ion-virtual-scroll is not a known element

Tags: angular, ionic3

```
<ion-virtual-scroll [items]="churchNewsList" approxItemHeight="120px">
        <ion-item *virtualItem="let news">
          {{ news }}
        </ion-item>
</ion-virtual-scroll>
```

I am getting this error

```
Can't bind to 'items' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-virtual-scroll'.
1. If 'ion-virtual-scroll' is an Angular component and it has 'items' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-virtual-scroll' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

how to include it in NgModule as mentioned. [Official Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll) doesnt state anything like this.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem, but searching I find `ion-scroll` doesn't exist anymore, `div` could be use instead

The above `css` could be actualized like the following

```css
div[scrollx=true],div[scrolly=true] {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div[scrollx=true] {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

div[scrolly=true] {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The solution is from the `Ionic Team` and you see in [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14933)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in this way, I think it will help you.

In html file:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div scrollY="true" id="scroll-list">
    <ion-list *ngFor="let item of list">
      <ion-item>
       {{ item }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

In scss file:

```
#scroll-list{
height: 200px;
```

}